# Intermediate pointers in cast must be "const qualified" - why?

Tags: c, gcc, constants, volatile

In the following code...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern void get_buffer_from_HW_driver(volatile uint32_t **p);

void getBuffer(volatile uint32_t **pp)
{
    // Write an address into pp, that is obtained from a driver
    // The underlying HW will be DMA-ing into this address,
    // so the data pointed-to by the pointer returned by this
    // call are volatile.
    get_buffer_from_HW_driver(pp);
}

void work()
{
    uint32_t *p = NULL;
    getBuffer((volatile uint32_t **)&p);
}
```

...the compiler rightfully detects that any potential accesses to the data pointed to by `p` inside `work` are dangerous accesses. As-is, the code instructs the compiler that it is safe to emit code that optimizes away repeated read accesses to `*p` - which is indeed wrong.

But the weird thing is, that the warning emitted by compiling this code...

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-qual constqual.c
```

...doesn't complain about the loss of `volatile` - it instead recommends using `const`:

```
constqual.c: In function ‘work’:
constqual.c:20:15: warning: to be safe all intermediate pointers in cast from 
                   ‘uint32_t ** {aka unsigned int **}’ to ‘volatile uint32_t ** 
                   {aka volatile unsigned int **}’ must be ‘const’ qualified
                   [-Wcast-qual]
 getBuffer((volatile uint32_t **)&p);
           ^
```

I cannot see how `const` makes sense here.

P.S. Note that adding `volatile` in front of the `uint32_t *p`, as expected, fixes the issue. My question is why GCC recommends `const` instead of `volatile`.

Comment: I would suspect that you've found a bug in the compiler message. Most likely the compiler treats all type qualifiers according to the same rules, but "volatile-correctness" is a somewhat rare beast compared to the commonly used "const-correctness". So maybe when coding this, they "hardcoded" the word `const` into the message without realising that the same applies to `volatile`, `restrict` and `_Atomic` as well.

Comment: Note that `clang` does emit the same warning (with slightly different wording, but referring to `const`). Is there a way to find the source of such warning messages?

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, it seems likely. I opened [a ticket in GCC's Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84166) - let's see what the devs say.

Comment: @Lundin GCC dev replied - summarized my understanding of their response below.

Comment: @Lundin Const-correctness requires that `Foo ***` safely converts to `Foo const * const * const *`. Perhaps surprisingly, volatile-correctness does **not** mean `Foo ***` safely converts to `Foo volatile * volatile * volatile *` --- it converts to  `Foo volatile * const * const *`. This is what the message is saying.

Comment: @n.m. Where did you get that from? C11 6.3.2.3/2 speaks of qualifiers only. `const` is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Lundin Not from the C standard. C type system is not advanced enough to recognise this. (C++ type system is). In C you need a cast to convert `Foo ***` to `Foo const * const * const*` (the standard says this) but the conversion is safe (the standard does not say this). The parallel conversion with `volatile` is unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [I raised a ticket in GCC's Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84166) about this... and Joseph Myers has answered with a laconic answer:

> No, GCC is not confused.  It's saying that it's type-safe to convert 
>   `uint32_t **` to `volatile uint32_t *const *`, but not to convert it to 
>   `volatile uint32_t *`.

...and he also added a reference to [this part of the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).

I have to admit that my first reaction to this was a *"say what?"*. I quickly tested the suggestion, changing the code to make it use the proposed declaration (and cast) instead...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern void get_buffer_from_HW_driver(volatile uint32_t * const *p);
void getBuffer(volatile uint32_t * const *pp)
{
    // Write an address into pp, that is obtained from a driver
    // The underlying HW will be DMA-ing into this address,
    // so the data pointed-to by the pointer returned by this
    // call are volatile.
    get_buffer_from_HW_driver(pp);
}

void work()
{
    uint32_t *p = NULL;
    getBuffer((volatile uint32_t * const *)&p);
}

$ gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-qual constqual.c

$
```

...and indeed, no warning anymore.

So I went ahead and read the relevant FAQ - and I think I understand a bit more of what is happening. By adding the `const` modifier, the parameter we are passing is *(reading from right to left, as we're supposed to do in this kind of C syntax)*:

> a pointer to a *constant* pointer (that will never change) that points to volatile data

This indeed maps very well to what is happening here: I am getting a pointer that points to volatile data, that is a driver-provided buffer - i.e. one that **I indeed am not allowed to change**, since it comes from pre-allocated lists of buffers that the driver itself allocated. Modifying the pointer that `get_buffer_from_HW_driver` returned would make no sense; it's not mine to modify, I can only use it as-is.

I confess I am really surprised that C's typesystem (augmented with the really strong static-analysis checks of -Wcast-qual) can actually help in guaranteeing these semantics.

Many thanks to Joseph - and I'll leave the question open for a few weeks, in case someone else wants to elaborate more.

*P.S. Adding a mental note: from now on, when anyone claims that C is a simple language, I think I'll point them here.*

Comment: There's two issues here. One is that _pointer-to-pointer_ is not compatible with _qualified-pointer-to-pointer_. Fine, that's a FAQ, nobody is arguing about that. The other issue is that gcc brings in `const` out of the blue. And there is nothing magical with `const` as such. What applies here is C11 6.3.2.372 "For any qualifier _q_, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal." So where does `const` come from?

Comment: @Lundin C11 6.3.2 talks about implicit conversions. It has nothing to do with the issue in hand. We have a cast here. C11 permits any pointer to pointer cast in 6.5.4/3. The cast however is not safe, and gcc warns you about that.